# Amazon S3 Data Sharing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I have an AWS S3 bucket with different datasets in it. I need to share data with public users and internal users securely with different access levels. For example, one needs to use data for Tableau. The data also is needed to share with the public users who does not have AWS Accounts as a bidirectional workflow (they need to read and write). I know that using AWS S3 Access Points we can create different users with different access levels, but I'm assuming that Access Points is just usable within the AWS Account and for Internal purposes. How can we expose data securely for both internal and external users? Does Amazon Cognito works for this scenario?

Comment: Would your "public users" still need to authenticate somehow, or are you happy for anyone on the Internet to read and write to your bucket? Do you have an existing system that can identify/authenticate these users?

Comment: I need to authenticate users and each user shoul have different permissions to have access to the datasets. I'm thinking about Amazon Cognito but I'm not sure how?!